# Photoshop JavaScript to resize image and canvas to specific (not square) sizes

Tags: javascript, canvas, resize, photoshop

How can I use PhotoShop's JavaScript functionality to convert a set of hundreds of images to a specific, non-square size (e.g. 320x350px)?

Comment: You need to ask the question as if you don't know the answer/are asking someone else, including any relevant keywords to help others in the future :) (or people may vote to close)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Searching the web I've found many potential solutions but 100% of them converted to square sizes. So, I gathered a few and solved the problem myself.

Save the code below as a `.jsx` file in your Photoshop `\Presets\Scripts` folder. Then, make an ACTION if want to use it with many files.

```
// get a reference to the current (active) document and store it in a variable named "doc"
doc = app.activeDocument;  

// change the color mode to RGB.  Important for resizing GIFs with indexed colors, to get better results
doc.changeMode(ChangeMode.RGB);  

// these are our values for the END RESULT width and height (in pixels) of our image
var fWidth = 320;
var fHeight = 350;

// do the resizing.  if height > width (portrait-mode) resize based on height.  otherwise, resize based on width
if (doc.height > doc.width) {
    doc.resizeImage(null,UnitValue(fHeight,"px"),null,ResampleMethod.BICUBIC);
}
else {
    doc.resizeImage(UnitValue(fWidth,"px"),null,null,ResampleMethod.BICUBIC);
}

// Makes the default background white
var white = new SolidColor(); 
white.rgb.hexValue = "FFFFFF";
app.backgroundColor = white;

// Convert the canvas size as informed above for the END RESULT
app.activeDocument.resizeCanvas(UnitValue(fWidth,"px"),UnitValue(fHeight,"px"));

// our web export options
var options = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();
options.quality = 70;
options.format = SaveDocumentType.JPEG;
options.optimized = true;

var newName = 'web-'+doc.name+'.jpg';

doc.exportDocument(File(doc.path+'/'+newName),ExportType.SAVEFORWEB,options);
```

Comment: Where I got most of the code: https://coffeeshopped.com/2008/11/conditional-image-resizing-with-photoshop-and-javascript