# Photoshop CC Batch Action TinyPNG Plugin

Tags: batch-file, automation, photoshop

I've got a folder with several subfolders in it where my images are stored.

The folder structure looks like this:

[image: Folder structure]

I want to create a batch command that takes the "All Products" Folder as the source folder, uses the tinyPNG Photoshop Plugin (https://tinypng.com/) and stores the compressed files of every product like this: All Products --> Product X --> Compressed Images

Is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far? (In terms of scripting.)

Comment: Please post the folder structure as text rather than as image; text can easily be copied for potential answerers to be used for testing, but images cannot, so other had to re-type everything, which reduces the change of getting answers...

Comment: @aschipfl I tried posting it as text but stackoverflow deleted the breaks so it was hard to see what it should look like.

Comment: @treintje I tried the Batch Automation wizard but no actual code samples

Comment: @AlexGogl People would be a lot more willing to help If you actually try to write the script yourself. If you get stuck or need help along the way, update your post with the things that you've tried so far. To get you started, I recommend you to read the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9649214

Comment: Then learn how to [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) (code blocks) properly (so in the editor, click the `{}` button or press _Ctrl+K_ to apply code block formatting)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually went with something different: The script now opens a folder, gets all the jpeg, png and tif images in there, resizes them to squares with a white canvas (nice for woocommerce and other ecommerce systems), compresses them with the tinyPNG plugin and subsequently overwrites the existing files, this way folders don't have to be created on the fly and the pictures stay in the same folder, you just need to copy all your original images and let them be overriden.

With the script it's possible to transform a portrait mode or landscape mode image to a square (works by resizing the pic and extending the canvas) with the dimensions of your choosing (in this case 2000x2000), so every image looks equal in a shop system. On the left side you can see the original one and on the right the resized and compressed one: [image]
[image]

How to use: First of all you need to buy the tinyPNG Plugin or use your own export logic (say Standard Photoshop Web Export), then save the code as a .jsx file and put it in your Photoshop -> Presets -> Scripts folder. Now you should see a new option in the File -> Automate section (if not restart PS). To batch resize and compress all pictures in a folder (even subfolders) you first need to open a picture of the root folder in photoshop, then press the "Resize images to Square and Compress..." button, a dialog will appear which prompts you to choose the folder. Now let it run (can take pretty long with a lot of images)

Now for the compression rate: [image]

TinyPNG really does a good job at compressing images.

Here the final script:

```
/*

// Get images from a folder recursively resize to square and compress with tinyPNG
// Copyright (c) 2017 Alex Gogl

<javascriptresource>
<menu>automate</menu>
<name>$$$/JavaScripts/ToSquareCompress/Menu=Resize images to Square and Compress...</name>
<eventid>7b078a04-ba43-4214-8eda-4026a5d2bd33</eventid>
</javascriptresource>

*/

function compressFile(file, percentage) {

    // Open the file without dialogs like Adobe Camera Raw
    var opener = new ActionDescriptor();
    opener.putPath(charIDToTypeID("null"), file);
    executeAction(charIDToTypeID("Opn "), opener, DialogModes.NO);

    // Select the opened document
    var document = app.activeDocument;

    // Change the color space to RGB if needed
    if (document.mode == DocumentMode.INDEXEDCOLOR) {
        document.changeMode(ChangeMode.RGB);
    }

    // Switch to 8 bit RGB if the image is 16 bit
    if (document.bitsPerChannel == BitsPerChannelType.SIXTEEN) {
        convertBitDepth(8);
    }

    // Choose the scale percentage
    if (percentage === undefined || percentage < 10 || percentage > 100) {
      percentage = 100;
    }

    //-----------START RESIZE LOGIC-----------
    // these are our values for the END RESULT width and height (in pixels) of our image
    var fWidth = 2000;
    var fHeight = 2000;

    // do the resizing. if height > width (portrait-mode) resize based on height. otherwise, resize based on width. if height equals width do nothing
    //ResamlpleMethod set to BICUBICSHARPER due to most images being resized to a smaller resolution
    if (document.height > document.width) {
      document.resizeImage(null,UnitValue(fHeight,"px"),null,ResampleMethod.BICUBICSHARPER);
    }
    else {
      document.resizeImage(UnitValue(fWidth,"px"),null,null,ResampleMethod.BICUBICSHARPER);
    }

    // Makes the default background white
    var white = new SolidColor();
    white.rgb.hexValue = "FFFFFF";
    app.backgroundColor = white;

    // Convert the canvas size as informed above for the END RESULT
    app.activeDocument.resizeCanvas(UnitValue(fWidth,"px"),UnitValue(fHeight,"px"));
    //-----------END RESIZE LOGIC-----------

    // Compress the document
    var tinify = new ActionDescriptor();
    tinify.putPath(charIDToTypeID("In  "), file); /* Overwrite original! */
    tinify.putUnitDouble(charIDToTypeID("Scl "), charIDToTypeID("#Prc"), percentage);
    tinify.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID("FlTy"), charIDToTypeID("tyFT"), charIDToTypeID("tyJP")); /* Force JPEG */

    var compress = new ActionDescriptor();
    compress.putObject(charIDToTypeID("Usng"), charIDToTypeID("tinY"), tinify);
    executeAction(charIDToTypeID("Expr"), compress, DialogModes.NO);

    document.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
}

function convertBitDepth(bitdepth) {
    var id1 = charIDToTypeID("CnvM");
    var convert = new ActionDescriptor();
    var id2 = charIDToTypeID("Dpth");
    convert.putInteger(id2, bitdepth);
    executeAction(id1, convert, DialogModes.NO);
}

function compressFolder(folder) {
    // Recursively open files in the given folder
    var children = folder.getFiles();
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        var child = children[i];
        if (child instanceof Folder) {
          compressFolder(child);
        } else {
            /* Only attempt to compress PNG,JPG,TIFF files. */
            if ((child.name.slice(-5).toLowerCase() == ".jpeg")||(child.name.slice(-4).toLowerCase() == ".jpg" || ".png" || ".tif")) {
                compressFile(child);
            }
        }
    }
}

if (confirm("Warning. You are about to compress all JPEG files in the chosen folder. This cannot be undone.\n\rAre you sure you want to continue?")) {
    try {
        // Let user select a folder
        compressFolder(Folder.selectDialog("Choose a folder with JPEG/PNG/TIF images to compress with TinyJPG"));
        alert("All JPEG/PNG/TIF files compressed.");
    } catch(error) {
        alert("Error while processing: " + error);
    }
}
```

Note: if you have an image where i.e the object (like a sunbrella) is not aligned in the middle, the final picture will also not be aligned in the middle, if anyone has ideas on how to fix that I'll be glad to listen.

Sources: [Photoshop JavaScript to resize image and canvas to specific (not square) sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580923/photoshop-javascript-to-resize-image-and-canvas-to-specific-not-square-sizes)

https://tinypng.com/photoshop/support#tips-tricks